# creating QPixmap object with a loop in Qt?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, loops, qpixmap

i am trying to learn qt to make a project for uni.
i have this code, it is working but is really not good.
my question is, how can i make it properly, more elegant?
need to create 20 objects(cars) and add the images to them. would it work with a loop?

```
QPixmap map(":/images/Scene002.png");
ui->map->setPixmap(map);
QPixmap car(":/images/Car.png");
ui->car->setPixmap(car);
QPixmap car2(":/images/car (2).png");
ui->car2->setPixmap(car2);
QPixmap car3(":/images/car (3).png");
ui->car3->setPixmap(car3);
QPixmap car4(":/images/car (4).png");
ui->car4->setPixmap(car4);
QPixmap car5(":/images/car (5).png");
ui->car5->setPixmap(car5);
QPixmap car6(":/images/car (6).png");
ui->car6->setPixmap(car6);
QPixmap car7(":/images/car (7).png");
ui->car7->setPixmap(car7);
QPixmap car8(":/images/car (8).png");
ui->car8->setPixmap(car8);
QPixmap car9(":/images/car (9).png");
ui->car9->setPixmap(car9);
QPixmap car10(":/images/car (10).png");
ui->car10->setPixmap(car10);
QPixmap car11(":/images/car (11).png");
ui->car11->setPixmap(car11);
QPixmap car12(":/images/car (12).png");
ui->car12->setPixmap(car12);
QPixmap car13(":/images/car (13).png");
ui->car13->setPixmap(car13);
QPixmap car14(":/images/car (14).png");
ui->car14->setPixmap(car14);
QPixmap car15(":/images/car (15).png");
ui->car15->setPixmap(car15);
QPixmap car16(":/images/car (16).png");
ui->car16->setPixmap(car16);
QPixmap car17(":/images/car (17).png");
ui->car17->setPixmap(car17);
QPixmap car18(":/images/car (18).png");
ui->car18->setPixmap(car18);
QPixmap car19(":/images/car (19).png");
ui->car19->setPixmap(car19);
QPixmap car20(":/images/car (20).png");
ui->car20->setPixmap(car20);
QPixmap nstation(":/images/NStation.png");
ui->nstation->setPixmap(nstation);
QPixmap npark(":/images/NPark.png");
ui->npark->setPixmap(npark);
QPixmap nmall(":/images/Mall.png");
ui->nmall->setPixmap(nmall);

gMap = ui->map->geometry();
gCar[1] = ui->car->geometry();
gCar[2] = ui->car2->geometry();
gCar[3] = ui->car3->geometry();
gCar[4] = ui->car4->geometry();
gCar[5] = ui->car5->geometry();
gCar[6] = ui->car6->geometry();
gCar[7] = ui->car7->geometry();
gCar[8] = ui->car8->geometry();
gCar[9] = ui->car9->geometry();
gCar[10] = ui->car10->geometry();
gCar[11] = ui->car11->geometry();
gCar[12] = ui->car12->geometry();
gCar[13] = ui->car13->geometry();
gCar[14] = ui->car14->geometry();
gCar[15] = ui->car15->geometry();
gCar[16] = ui->car16->geometry();
gCar[17] = ui->car17->geometry();
gCar[18] = ui->car18->geometry();
gCar[19] = ui->car19->geometry();
gCar[20] = ui->car20->geometry();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your objects had objectnames then you can do that, it then becomes a matter of string concatenation in which I will recommend using

```
(QLabel)ui->findChild(QString(sprintf("car%d", counter)))->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString(sprintf(":/images/car (%d).png", counter))));
```

And the above code will work if all the objects are QLabel derived and objectnames are in the format carX, where X is a number between 0 and 19 or 1 and 20, depending on how you named them.

Comment: this is what i got as error.





error: 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'findChildren' (QLabel)ui->findChild(QString(sprintf("car%d", counter)))->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString(sprintf(":/images/car (%d).png", counter))));